# how to exit the other window while maintaining the original window

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

i'm doing a pop-out error window. and I tried various things but it didn't work. what i want to do is just close the error window that popped-out while still maintaining the original window.

in my code:

```
final Display display = Display.getDefault();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN|SWT.RESIZE);
shell.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
}
});
shell.setSize(304, 195);
shell.setText("Error Occur")
```

now i'm trying to close this window with this code that's bind in a button:

```
    Button OKbutton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    OKbutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            shell.isDisposed();
        }
    });
    OKbutton.setBounds(125, 123, 75, 25);
    OKbutton.setText("OK");
```

i also tried, shell.close(); but it didnt work. But when i tried the display.close(); it close both my original window and the error window.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the part of code where you actually open the popup dialog, I can only guess what the problem is:

The fact that both windows close suggests that you use the same `Shell` for both. Hence, when you close one, the other closes as well.

A simple solution would be to create a `new Shell()` for the popup window which you then can close without messing with the original `Shell`.

---

**However**, both SWT and JFace provide classes for popup dialogs. Using these would make your life easier and make your application look and behave more native.

There is a nice tutorial about both SWT and JFace Dialogs [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html). The tutorial shows you how to use a set of predefined Dialogs (e.g. error messages, file chooser, ...) as well as how to create your own Dialog.